# Parameterization of a closed curve on a sphere

Tags: parametric, spherical-coordinates, curves

I'm looking for a parameterization of a closed curve *C* on a sphere.

assume the projections of *C* on y-z, x-z, x-y plane are f(x), g(y), h(z), respectively, and

${\oint}f(x)dx={\oint}g(y)dy=0$, and ${\oint}h(z)dz=z_0, 0<z_0<1$.

My question is the following:

1. Is there any restriction on f(x), g(y), h(z) so that such a closed curve exists on a sphere?
2. How to obtain the parametrization of such a curve using spheric coordinates?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there are  are restrictions. If the $yz$-projection is the circle of the same radius as the sphere, then the other two projections must be line segments (the curve is a flat circle). Similar restriction arises if one of projections is sufficiently close to being a circle of such radius.